# useState failed to set up data outside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list and I want the list to be updated when a button clicked. And I would like to return a combined result of newly added content and what was originally in the list:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const profile = () = {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    let newData = useRef([])
    newData.current = ['abc']
    useEffect(() => {
        let nData = ['bbbbcc']
        newData.current = [...newData.current, nData]
        }, [data])

    const onClickAdd = () = {
        **setData(newData.current)**
        **console.log(data)**
    }
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onClickAdd}>Add data</button>
        </>)
}
```

Yes I could use a `concat` or `push()` function for a much simpler way, but considering the data might change later, I would prefer to use a function. And what I don't understand here is that when I do the `console.log(data)` it returned `[Object Object]` as if it is not there. I understand that this is because the `data` was checked before it was generated in react DOM, but i think it should still be a global variable so even when we checked inside another function (`onClickAdd`), it should still return the combined result of `newData.current` and `nData`, which will be `['abc', 'bbbbcc']`?

Comment: It looks like a very convoluted way to do `setData([...data, newStuff])` ^^

Comment: Every render you do this -> `newData.current = ['abc']`  so it will never ever be anything other than `['abc']`

Comment: @moonwave99 do you mean that i should remove the useEffect block, and directly call the setData in the way you mentioned under the function?

Comment: @Keith Thank you for the explanation! Now i see

Comment: @Keith I also thought that I did change the value of `newData.current` in `useEffect` hook, how come it gets ignored, or somehow not rendering in this case?

Comment: effect runs after render and since it's a ref and not a state, it doesn't cause a rerender

Comment: @nullptr I moved the parts outside of `useEffect`and do a `console.log(newData.current)`, it still shows as Object Object, why?

Answer (score -1):

```
export const Profile = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const newData = useRef([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  let nData = ['bbbbcc'];
  newData.current = [...newData.current, ...nData];
 }, []);

 const onClickAdd = () => {
  setData(newData.current);
  console.log(newData.current);
 };

  return (
   <>
    <button onClick={onClickAdd}>Add data</button>
    <div>
     {data.map((item, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
         <p>Mail: {item.mail}</p>
         <p>Display: {item.display}</p>
       </div>
     ))}
    </div>
   </>
  );
 };
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {mail, display}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @maoyi sure, will modify the code now